# With Flask, how can I serve robots.txt and sitemap.xml as static files?

Tags: python, flask, static-files

I've read on quiet a few places that serving static files should be left to the server, for example in a couple of the answers on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239825/static-files-in-flask-robot-txt-sitemap-xml-mod-wsgi). But I use the OpenShift PaaS, and can't figure out how to modify the .htaccess file there.

I came across this [piece of code](http://code.google.com/r/lipiridis-skiptrack/source/browse/main/sitemap.py?spec=svn8cd861620861a94f984a5bc2de2fcbda2773296e&r=8cd861620861a94f984a5bc2de2fcbda2773296e) that serves the sitemap from a template. I did that on my app for both the sitemap, and robots.txt, like so -

```
@app.route("/sitemap.xml")
def sitemap_xml():
    response= make_response(render_template("sitemap.xml"))
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'
    return response

@app.route("/robots.txt")
def robots_txt():
    return render_template("robots.txt")
```

Is there any harm in this, or is my approach okay?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Put `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` into your app's `static` directory and define this view:

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory

@app.route('/robots.txt')
@app.route('/sitemap.xml')
def static_from_root():
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, request.path[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks - this will do for Flask apps on Heroku. Seems to be pretty much impossible to get Heroku's (Nginx-based) router to directly serve static content, unless it's in the `static` or `public` directory of a project. Would prefer, of course, to serve `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` directly with Nginx, in environments that let me do it.

Comment: Correction to my above comment: looks like Heroku doesn't use Nginx at all, it actually passes all requests (including requests to the `static` or `public` dir) directly to an app process (e.g. directly to Gunicorn for a typical Python app), only going via a custom proxy / load-balancer called Vegur - see: http://superuser.com/questions/837925/what-is-vegur-appearing-in-http-headers

Answer (score 13):

Flask has built in support for serving static files.

Make a `/static` directory and put your files there. Then, when you instantiate `Flask`, specify the `static_url_path` parameter:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/')
```

The default is to serve static files from the `/static/` path, but you want them served from `/` so they are where expected.

See the [Flask API Docs](http://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/) for more info.

In addition to overhead and unnecessary code, the problem with your approach is if / when one of the files you want to serve contains something that looks like a template tag to `render_template` -- you can cause a rendering error. If you were to read the file into memory (once, not inside the method) then use that string as the body of the response without calling `render_template`, you would at least avoid that problem.

Comment: You mean something like this - `robots= open(cwd+'/static/robots.txt', 'r').read()` and then `return robots` in the `robots_txt` function?

Comment: @elssar - I don't think you should reinvent file caching - check out http://packages.python.org/Flask-Cache/

Comment: @elssar Yes, that's what I mean, but I'm not suggesting you actually do that. I was just pointing out that if you were intending to read in and output static files, `render_template` wasn't doing just that.

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to set **static_url_path** to root url

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', static_url_path='')
```