# Flask url not found

Tags: python, url, flask, robots.txt

i created a robots.txt , i've looking for how to include it in mywebsite.com/robots.txt and i found Flask

This is my code

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory
app = Flask('maksc', static_folder='/static')


@app.route('/robots.txt')
def static_from_root():
return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, request.path[1:])
```

Everything ok , but when i go to mywebsite.com/robots.txt it cant found the page , it triggers python "Page not found" displaying all the urls defined

Comment: Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048779/with-flask-how-can-i-serve-robots-txt-and-sitemap-xml-as-static-files and/or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239825/static-files-in-flask-robot-txt-sitemap-xml-mod-wsgi and/or here https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2012/11/21/serving-static-files-from-root-and-not-static-using-flask/

Comment: if it's displaying the url defined in the error page, then that's probably django's server

Comment: It is django's server error page

Comment: Why you use `'maksc'` instead `__name__`? By `__name__` you will resolve module, by module you will resolve `root_path`, by `root_path` you will resolve static folder root (`os.path.join(root_path, static_folder)`).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting static_url_path

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/')
```

This means that files will be served from / instead of /static/blabla/

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment it looks like you're using Django. Try adding this to your urls.py:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
    (r'^robots\.txt$', direct_to_template,
     {'template': 'robots.txt', 'mimetype': 'text/plain'}),
)
```

Example taken from here: http://fredericiana.com/2010/06/09/three-ways-to-add-a-robots-txt-to-your-django-project/

Comment: Didnt work either , i am thinking , i have to create an url on urls.py ? Because it doesnt seems to find anything not even the url

Comment: Im no Flask expert but I can't find anything about an urls.py here? Isn't that Django? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/

Comment: Yes i am using Django , u cant combine them ?

Comment: Ehm...I don't think that's a normal use case at all? Aren't they two different frameworks?

I just tried this simple Flask app, and it worked for me:

`from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/robots.txt')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()`

Comment: I am such a noob haha , i did a little research , you cant use both , i will import robots.txt from django , thz for the help anyway

Comment: I found this, sure you CAN do it, but it's not recommended...
Feel free to accept my "answer". http://tofudonuts.blogspot.se/2010/09/combining-flask-and-django.html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the static_folder='static' without the slash, as it may interpret it as a top root diretory.

Comment: Tried , doesnt work , as i said above , shouldn't i have to create an url on ulrs.py ?

Comment: no, you don't need to define url.py, how are you running the application server? and is the folder the app resides in called maksc ?

Comment: I am running it on console if that's what you mean and yes its called like that