# Flask-Login - User returns to Anonymous after successful login then redirect

Tags: python, flask-login

I'm trying just to setup a base login model with developed code mostly from [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

After my user successfully logs in and I issue a `redirect(url_for('index'))`, the user loses his authentication and returns to the value [`flask_login.AnonymousUserMixin`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.AnonymousUserMixin).

I realize there are some simple workarounds but I'm trying to understand why my code doesn't work like the examples.

I must be missing something simple or a lack understanding of Flask-Login. How can the user remain logged in after a redirect?

**__init__.py**

```python
...
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login"
...
```

**models.py**

```python
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    pwdhash = db.Column(db.String(54))

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, email, username, password):
        ...
    def get_id(self):
        return(self.username)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User is:%r>' % (self.username)
```

**routes.py**

```python
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.get(user_id)
    except:
        return None

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate():
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data.lower()).first()
            login_user(user, remember=False)
            assert current_user.is_authenticated
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            return render_template('login.html', form=form)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

I have reviewed [flask-login user is set to anonymous after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150626/flask-login-user-is-set-to-anonymous-after-login) but that login method is different than the one above.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I need to answer my own question on a dumb oversight that I should have caught (bleary eyes?)

Simple fix in `def load_user(user_id):` where I needed to replace the line

Bad: `return User.query.get(user_id)`

Good: `return User.query.filter_by(username=user_id).first()`

I suppose the take-away is the importance of `def load_user()` in preserving session integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Add these functions to your `User` class.

```
def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

def is_active(self):
    return self.active

def is_anonymous(self):
    return False
```

If I remember correctly,`Flask-Login` requires them in your `User` class.

`self.active` is a Boolean field. Trivially, it tells `Flask-Login` whether the user is active or not. You might want to declare it using `active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)`.

Comment: From what I understand, UserMixin in class 'User(UserMixin, db.Model):' includes those functions. However, I inserted those functions w/out UserMixin and I get the same results. Can't find any documentation on self.active`, doesn't appear to have any effects –