# Unable to retrieve files from send_from_directory() in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a html file which references static object like this

```
<img src="img/snacks.png">
<link href="css/bluestrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hence the browser tries to call this via and flask fails to do so

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/img/snacks.png
```

There are lots of such references across multiple files hence changing the references is not possible. How do i serve these static files from FLASK

I have copied all these static files to the 'static' folder and tried this

```
@app.route('/<path:filename>')  
def send_file(filename):  
      return send_from_directory('/static', filename)
```

However this does not work, Is there any other way to do this ? or what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)

Answer (score 33):

In production, you don't want to serve static files using the flask server. I suggest you use a proper web server to do that.

For dev, since you don't want to use `url_for`, you can try to initialize your flask app as below. This way, flask knows where your static files are.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')  

@app.route('/<path:filename>')  
def send_file(filename):  
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, filename)
```

See this post with a lot of info
[Static files in Flask - robot.txt, sitemap.xml (mod_wsgi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239825/static-files-in-flask-robot-txt-sitemap-xml-mod-wsgi)

Comment: There are too many references of images / css files to change them using url_for function , that is why i don't want to change them . Is there no way to not change the html file and still serve them from python ?

Comment: with "main" blueprint can not use it

Comment: Flask `url_for` with `'static'` already calls `send_from_directory`, I don't see your point

Comment: One caveat for me was to make sure that `filename` is really just a filename and not a path to a file in a subdir.

The static folder can also be specified manually, but it needs to be the absolute path. Use `os.path.realpath()` to get it.

Answer (score 14):

If you look at the docs for [`send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory) you'll see that it takes the path to the directory in which the files are held *on disk*.  Unless you have your image files saved in a root-level directory named `static`, you'll want to update your file path:

```
send_from_directory("/some/path/to/static", "my_image_file.jpg")
```

That being said, if you are using this for anything that will be under any load, it is better to ensure that your *web server* serves the files, rather than serving static files from your application.

Comment: My files are stored in a folder called 'img' inside a root level directory called 'static', so effectively its stored at static/img/snacks.png and browser calls http://127.0.0.1:5000/img/snacks.png

Comment: @RijulJain - yes, but is that directory located at `/static` on disk?  That is, is it next to `usr`, `etc` and so on under `/` in your *file system* (not your webserver root)?

Comment: That is in my webserver root , how do i give path relative to my webserver root  ?

Comment: NOT a single answer from top to bottom can be used !

Answer (score 7):

Don't use Flask's built-in server in production. It is for development only! And don't use Flask to serve static assets. It's slow! In production use a webserver in front of Flask like apache2, nginx or lighttpd. These servers are able to rewrite a URL and serve static assets.

How to deploy Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/

How to rewrite a URL: [apache2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/), [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule), [lighttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite).

Answer (score 3):

I think a better way to do this would be:

```
import flask

# ...

@app.route('/img/<fname>')
def legacy_images(fname):
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('static', filename='img/' + fname), code=301)
```

Instead of sending the files on two different locations, this would do a permanent redirect to the proper URL. As others have said, it's also a good idea to serve static files directly with nginx or Apache.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove "/" before "/static" in your code:

```
send_from_directory('/static', filename)
```

change it to:

```
send_from_directory('static', filename)
```

However, in some environments, the server itself does not let running this command on the ***static*** folder/directory. Because it is set to be a static file server. For example, with the google cloud, you should build a directory called ***tmp*** beside the static folder and then do the send_from_directory command with the ***tmp*** folder:

```
return(send_from_directory('tmp', filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@app.route('/<path:filename>')  
def send_file(filename):
      from pathlib import Path
      root = Path('.')
      folder_path = root / 'static'
      return send_from_directory(folder_path, filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: While this code might answer the OP's question, you could make your answer much better by appending an explanation on how your code solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Flask Version 2.3
this is reference for documentation https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#flask.send_from_directory
this an example

```
@app.route('/download:')
def download():
    return send_from_directory(directory='static/files', path="cheat_sheet.pdf", as_attachment=False)
```

[app hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyLYK.png)