# how do I load image in python flask?

Tags: python, html, image, flask

so.... I'm a beginner in python flask trying to make a dashboard.

I have a folder where my uploaded pictures are located.

structure:

```
manage.py  # this is where I run the program.
src
    |--pic
        |--items
            |-- pic_here.jpg
```

how should I set up so I could load the picture and get it into `<img>`?

I tried searching but all they showed was how to set up static folders. I don't think this is one for static, the pictures are what I upload via dashboard.

in other words, src/pic/items is where my saved images are located and how do I set my flask to load this picture?

Comment: pictures **are** static resources... `url_for` in a Jinja template would load them to HTML.

Comment: oh..... so... I have to put `{{ url_for() }}` part into the img src right? ok, think I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1) You need something in Flask to know where your images are located on disk. 2) You don't need to use `url_for`, but that is just one way. You will need some variable to render into the `src` attribute that is relative to the hosted URL, yes. This is where a static resource folder is necessary. For example, you wouldn't put `http://example-site.com/src/pic/items/pic_here.jpg`, it would probably just be like `http://example-site.com/pic/pic_here.jpg`

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207761/where-does-flask-look-for-image-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What i would advise is to create a view that serves the image (a simple API).

```
app = Flask(__name__, upload_folder='upload') 

@app.route('/img/<path:filename>') 
def send_file(filename): 
    return send_from_directory(app.upload_folder, filename)
```

This should get the job done, but you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681762/unable-to-retrieve-files-from-send-from-directory-in-flask) for more.

Answer (score 6):

When you create a 'static' folder, you can use `url_for` in jinja to load your pictures in html.

Put your pictures in:
`/app_homedirectory/static/PictureName.jpg`

Then you can load your pictures in html with:
`<img src={{ url_for('static', filename='PictureName.jpg') }}>`

This works out of the box, you just need to create a folder named 'static' and flask will recognize it.

add `from flask import url_for` to the file that contains the view of your rendered html document.