# flask send_from_directory results in TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use the function `send_from_directory` but regardless of whether I supply an absolute path or a relative path I result in the error

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/nova/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 269, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/nova/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 260, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/nova/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 231, in write
    status < 200 or status in (204, 304)):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I have no problem using the `send_file` function, provided it's an absolute path. However based on the documentation, `send_file` only accepts absolute paths and if a relative path is given, it is then treated as a relative path to the root path. Hence me trying the function `send_from_directory`. My code is below, what am I doing wrong?

Note, the image is located in the directory `static` one up from the current directory

Also I've been looking at the issue
[Unable to retrieve files from send_from_directory() in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681762/unable-to-retrieve-files-from-send-from-directory-in-flask) , based on the second solution, does that mean my image file has to be located somewhere under root? ie `/root/static`?

```
full_file_path = get_image("pic.gif")

def get_image(image_name):
    path = '../static'
    # path = '/home/static'
    try:
        print("path",path)
        print("image_name", image_name)
        return send_from_directory(path, filename=image_name)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("error")
        abort(404)
```

Comment: Do all images passed in as image_name have a certain format for this route handler? The error seems like one of the library functions is trying to compare (<) strings with ints.

Comment: I've only tried one file and its a .gif file. I notice I get the same error when I try to use a relative path for send_file(). ie ../previous_file_dir

Comment: According to https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file, send_file() bases relative paths on the root_path variable, not the path /root. If you didn't set this variable for the Flask app, then try setting it to the app's working directory (assuming that's where you want to take files out of based on your code path = '../static')

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, however, the main problem for me is that I don't want to have to hard code any directories. Since the location of where I want the code to be deployed are different (development, test, production), the absolute path of the project directories can be different.

Comment: I see. Have you tried os.getcwd() and then playing around with os.path.abspath()? You could still use relative paths once you get the working directory, and then use abspath to create an absolute path to play nicely with Flask. 

See abspath() here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks