# Serving lots of images from a flask server

Tags: python, image, flask, webserver, static-content

I am trying to design a site using Flask for a store and need to serve the customers with lots of product pictures.
I came across [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681762/unable-to-retrieve-files-from-send-from-directory-in-flask#answer-17681884:%7E:text=24,proper%20web%20server%20to%20do%20that.) that said:

> In production, you don't want to serve static files using the flask server. I suggest you use a proper web server to do that

What does a "proper web server" mean and how does one set that up?

Currently, I have the images served like this - example:

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="{{url_for('static', filename='/images/prducts/full/1.jpg' )}}" alt="First slide">
<img class="d-block w-100" src="{{url_for('static', filename='/images/prducts/full/2.jpg' )}}" alt="Second slide">
```

Comment: `flask` should run with web server `apache`, `nginx` or other which can serve static files much faster. See [Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/) and [Web Servers](https://www.fullstackpython.com/web-servers.html) and [WSGI Servers](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html) - there is example config for `nginx` which runs `wsgi server` which runs `flask`

Comment: BTW: you don't have to change code in HTML when you use `apache`, `nginx`, etc. so you still use `{{url_for('static', filename=... ) }}`. Request from client's browser goes first to `apache`/`nginx` which sends to client all files with url `/static` and other urls sends to `flask` which generates pages, send back to `apache`/`nginx` and it sends it back to client.